# Intellij: facet vs module vs framework support

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm creating a maven project in Intellij. For the IDE to function properly, you have to declare support for various aspects of Java EE/Spring functionality. However, adding support seems inconsistent. For example

- to add servlet support, I have to right click on the project and "add framework support -> web application" (optionally creates `web.xml`)
- to add support for JPA, "project structure -> facets -> JPA" (optionally creates `persistence.xml`)
- to add support for spring data, "project structure -> modules -> Spring data JPA". Adding this, **forces me** to download new spring data libraries, which override the ones downloaded from maven. Although Intellij sees that the libraries already exist, it gives me no option to keep the existing ones

My question is

- is there a significant difference between the 3 options, or is it an inconsistency of Intellij?
- is there a way to add support for *spring data jpa* without overwriting the existing libraries?